# Asp.net VB Webform. How to get li items from ul list at codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, html-lists, code-behind

i need help ;) i populate a ul with listitems from code behind trough Asp.net and htmlGenericControl.

The list items appear and these items are dropable and sortable into different uls trough jquery sortable and connectedSortable function. This works fine.

For example i have 3 lists. UnorderdLists(ul's) A, B and C.
List A is populated with a few items. Now i can drag and drop theses list items from list A to list B or C.

Now i need help how can i see or get (in/at codebehind) which item is in list B or C ?!

Info:

- I dont use bulletlist because i think dropable/sortable would give me some trouble instead.

  - My ul's have added runat="server", do my li's have to had this aswell?

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: hi thx for the comment. i had just three connected lists.. soo not that much of code. i will now try baro's suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use a custom or not standard controls, I prefer to use hidden fields and store the data in a custom way (values with char separator for example).

You can populate via Javascript/Jquery your hidden fields at your specific events and then from codebehind you can read the hidden fields.

**UPDATE with example**

This is only one possiblity, but more simple probably is JQuery AJAX.

webform.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="webform.aspx.vb" Inherits="ajax_test.webform" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#send').click(function () {
                $('#<%= HFTest.ClientID %>').val($('#theValue').val());
                __doPostBack('<%= btn_force_async.ClientID %>','');
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
                Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

                function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                    // Fire before the AJAX request

                }
                function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                    // Fire after the AJAX request
                    if ($('#<%=HFReturnMessage.ClientID %>').val() == 'ok') {
                        alert('ok!');
                    } else {
                        alert($('#<%=HFReturnMessage.ClientID %>').val());
                    }
                }

            </script>




            <input id="theValue" type="text" value="ok" />
            <input id="send" type="button" value="send value" />



            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPDHiddenFields" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFTest" runat="server" />

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HFReturnMessage" runat="server" />

                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>    
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_force_async" EventName="click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_force_async" runat="server" style="display:none;"/>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

webform.aspx.vb // The codebehind

```
Public Class webform
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If IsPostBack Then

            If HFTest.Value = "ok" Then
                HFTest.Value = ""
                HFReturnMessage.Value = "ok"
            Else
                HFTest.Value = ""
                HFReturnMessage.Value = "error, the HFTest is not ok ! "
            End If

            UPDHiddenFields.Update() 'Update hidden field panel on client side


        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hey. I added ur suggestion to my code. But if i press a button to get the hidden data from an item. the page reloads and the data, which was added with jquery, is gone.

Comment: I don't know exactly your case, but if you need that the page is not loaded again, then you must use AJAX requests.

Comment: @miocg3 I update the answer with a tested example. :)

Comment: Hi thank u very much. It worked well with the hidden field. Unfortanetly i havent enough Reputation to upvote ur help. But it is checked as Solution. As soon i will have 15 Rep my Upvote should count.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad I help you :)